# saving audio file in django

Tags: html, django

How to save the audio file but I'm not using form.py only views, HTML, models?
I uploaded my code below if you know a more simple method I'm all ears.

models.py code:

```
 class Message(models.Model):
    messager_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    message_text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    message_title = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, related_name='sender_doctor',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, related_name='reciever_doctor',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    send_message = models.DateTimeField(blank= True)
    read_message = models.DateTimeField(blank= True, null=True)
    mark_as_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recording = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/', blank= True, null=True)
```

views.py code:

```
 def writemessage(request, id):
    print("Please Write Message")
    docid = Doctor.objects.filter(doctor_id = id)
    print(docid)
    writemessage = Doctor.objects.exclude(doctor_id = id)
    cnt = {'writemessage':writemessage, 'docid':docid}
    if request.method == "POST":
        message_text = request.POST['message_text']
        message_title = request.POST['message_title']
        docotname = request.POST['receiver']
        receiver = Doctor.objects.get(doctor_id=docotname)
        sender = Doctor.objects.get(doctor_id=id)
        send_message = timezone.now()
        # read_message = timezone.now()
        recording = request.POST['recording']
        message = Message(message_text=message_text, message_title=message_title ,
        receiver=receiver, sender=sender, send_message=send_message)
        message.save()
        return render(request, 'message.html')
    return render(request, 'writemessage.html', cnt)
```

HTML code:

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block css %} 
  
.controls {
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 200px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 4px solid #f22f46;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f22f46;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
button:hover,
button:focus {
  background: #f22f46;
  color: #fff;
}
#recordings {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#recordings li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
#recordings audio {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em;
}
a {
  color: #0d122b;
}
.error {
  color: #f22f46;
  text-align: center;
}

{% endblock %} 
  {% load static %} 
  <script src="{% static '/js/recording.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>  
{%block body %} 

    <h1>My Write a Message Page</h1>
    <div class="container">
    {% for docid in docid %}
    
    
    <form method="post" id="form1" action="/message/writemessage/{{docid.doctor_id}}">
    {% endfor %}
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title: </label>
    <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="" name="message_title">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="doctorname">To: </label>
    {% for writemessage in writemessage %}
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="doctorname" name="receiver">
      <option value={{writemessage.doctor_id}}>{{writemessage.doctor_name}}</option>
    </select>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Write a Message:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="message_text"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="controls">
        <button type="button" id="mic">Get Microphone</button>
        <button type="button" id="record" hidden>Record</button>
      </div>
      <div id="recordings" value="recording"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" form="form1" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
    </div>
    
      <script>
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const getMic = document.getElementById('mic');
        const recordButton = document.getElementById('record');
        const list = document.getElementById('recordings');
        if ('MediaRecorder' in window) {
          getMic.addEventListener('click', async () => {
            getMic.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
            try {
              const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: true,
                video: false
              });
              const mimeType = 'audio/webm';
              let chunks = [];
              const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { type: mimeType });
              recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
                if (typeof event.data === 'undefined') return;
                if (event.data.size === 0) return;
                chunks.push(event.data);
              });
              recorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
                const recording = new Blob(chunks, {
                  type: mimeType
                });
                renderRecording(recording, list);
                chunks = [];
              });
              recordButton.removeAttribute('hidden');
              recordButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                if (recorder.state === 'inactive') {
                  recorder.start();
                  recordButton.innerText = 'Stop';
                } else {
                  recorder.stop();
                  recordButton.innerText = 'Record';
                }
              });
            } catch {
              renderError(
                'You denied access to the microphone so this demo will not work.'
              );
            }
          });
        } else {
          renderError(
            "Sorry, your browser doesn't support the MediaRecorder API, so this demo will not work."
          );
        }
      });

      function renderError(message) {
        const main = document.querySelector('main');
        main.innerHTML = `<div class="error"><p>${message}</p></div>`;
      }

      function renderRecording(blob, list) {
        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        //const li = document.createElement('li');
        const audio = document.createElement('audio');
        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.setAttribute('href', blobUrl);
        const now = new Date();
        anchor.setAttribute(
          'download',
          `recording-${now.getFullYear()}-${(now.getMonth() + 1)
            .toString()
            .padStart(2, '0')}-${now
            .getDay()
            .toString()
            .padStart(2, '0')}--${now
            .getHours()
            .toString()
            .padStart(2, '0')}-${now
            .getMinutes()
            .toString()
            .padStart(2, '0')}-${now
            .getSeconds()
            .toString()
            .padStart(2, '0')}.webm`
        );
        //anchor.innerText = 'Download';
        audio.setAttribute('src', blobUrl);
        audio.setAttribute('controls', 'controls');
        audio.setAttribute('name', 'recording');
        //audio.appendChild(audio);
        //li.appendChild(anchor);
        list.appendChild(audio);
      }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/writemessage/1

Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.9.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'msg.apps.MsgConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Work_Django_VS\textmsg\textmsg\envmsg\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 76, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)

During handling of the above exception ('recording'), another exception occurred:
  File "D:\Work_Django_VS\textmsg\textmsg\envmsg\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Work_Django_VS\textmsg\textmsg\envmsg\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Work_Django_VS\textmsg\textmsg\msg\views.py", line 75, in writemessage
    recording = request.POST['recording']
  File "D:\Work_Django_VS\textmsg\textmsg\envmsg\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /message/writemessage/1
Exception Value: 'recording'
```

mostly code exception that's why .................................................................................................................. Just ignore  it

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: added traceback

Comment: There is no form element that would upload any audio data that I can see.

Comment: see at the end of the script                                                    
         audio.setAttribute('name', 'recording');
         list.appendChild(audio);

Comment: Yes. That's not a form input element, that's an audio element.

Comment: oh now I understood what you mean can you tell me what should I use because I was thinking of using <input type="file"> but I can use src with it I need to add blobUrl.